Jasper Server - multi select query using rest API
enter image description here
Your task is to develop the application with the ability to retrieve dynamic elements from an external API. The application currently uses the API available at https://blablabla.com/api/structure to retrieve data.
Required steps:
Set up a connection to the API using the indicated endpoint: https://blablabla.com/api/structure.
In order to access data from the API, a beaver token is required. This token should be passed as part of the request to the API in the authorization header.
Implement a mechanism that will retrieve data from the API at application launch or in response to a user action.
After retrieving data from the API, the application should use this information to dynamically display items in the user interface.
Make sure that the application handles errors related to communication with the API and responds appropriately to any problems with data retrieval.
